# How to transfer jquery data from main file to an asp file?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, asp-classic

I have working autocomplete script, but it isn't work rapidly. Thus I decided to transfer my data another asp file. But i had a problem when i did this. My question is how to transfer my data to asp file? My working sample codes below (These are not my data. I retrieve data from MSSQL and at least 10000 record in it.).

```
<p>
<input id="autocomplete2" type="text" placeholder="U.S. state name">
<input id="autocomplete2-value" type="text" name="code">
</p>
<script>
    var data = [
        { value: "AL", label: "Alabama" },
        { value: "AK", label: "Alaska" },
        { value: "AZ", label: "Arizona" },
        { value: "AR", label: "Arkansas" },
        { value: "CA", label: "California" },
        { value: "CO", label: "Colorado" },
        { value: "CT", label: "Connecticut" },
        { value: "DE", label: "Delaware" },
        { value: "FL", label: "Florida" },
        { value: "GA", label: "Georgia" },
        { value: "HI", label: "Hawaii" },
        { value: "ID", label: "Idaho" },
        { value: "IL", label: "Illinois" },
        { value: "IN", label: "Indiana" },
        { value: "IA", label: "Iowa" },
        { value: "KS", label: "Kansas" },
        { value: "KY", label: "Kentucky" },
        { value: "LA", label: "Louisiana" },
        { value: "ME", label: "Maine" },
        { value: "MD", label: "Maryland" },
        { value: "MA", label: "Massachusetts" },
        { value: "MI", label: "Michigan" },
        { value: "MN", label: "Minnesota" },
        { value: "MS", label: "Mississippi" },
        { value: "MO", label: "Missouri" },
        { value: "MT", label: "Montana" },
        { value: "NE", label: "Nebraska" },
        { value: "NV", label: "Nevada" },
        { value: "NH", label: "New Hampshire" },
        { value: "NJ", label: "New Jersey" },
        { value: "NM", label: "New Mexico" },
        { value: "NY", label: "New York" },
        { value: "NC", label: "North Carolina" },
        { value: "ND", label: "North Dakota" },
        { value: "OH", label: "Ohio" },
        { value: "OK", label: "Oklahoma" },
        { value: "OR", label: "Oregon" },
        { value: "PA", label: "Pennsylvania" },
        { value: "RI", label: "Rhode Island" },
        { value: "SC", label: "South Carolina" },
        { value: "SD", label: "South Dakota" },
        { value: "TN", label: "Tennessee" },
        { value: "TX", label: "Texas" },
        { value: "UT", label: "Utah" },
        { value: "VT", label: "Vermont" },
        { value: "VA", label: "Virginia" },
        { value: "WA", label: "Washington" },
        { value: "WV", label: "West Virginia" },
        { value: "WI", label: "Wisconsin" },
        { value: "WY", label: "Wyoming" }
    ];
    $(function() {
        $("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
            source: data,
            focus: function(event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                // prevent autocomplete from updating the textbox
                event.preventDefault();
                // manually update the textbox and hidden field
                $(this).val(ui.item.label);
                $("#autocomplete2-value").val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: `i had a problem` when I did this isn't a proper problem description. How is the autocomplete currently working and why would moving it to another file help?

Comment: It is working slowly. It works rapid from another file. I tried json but script didn't accepted json codes in asp file. Thanks...

Comment: Not much of an explanation to work from and doesn't answer the questions

Comment: I'm sorry for my insufficient explanation. But I am using autocomplete more than one in a page. Thus increasing the page size is too. Page loading takes a long time. Thanks...

Comment: Suggest you use ajax for this with as much data as you are loading. See docs how to point to a server side url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution for the problem by @charlietfl helps. My jquery codes below.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#Uni" ).autocomplete({
        source: "rm_universite2.asp",
        minLength: 2
});
});
```

And rm_universite2.asp codes:

```
If rsUrun.RecordCount > 0 Then
i = 1
Sinirla = 10


output = "["

Do While Not rsUrun.EOF And i < (Sinirla + 1) 

output = output & "{""id"":""" & rsUrun("ID") & """,""value"":""" & rsUrun("Adi") & """},"

i = i + 1

rsUrun.MoveNext
Loop

output=Left(output,Len(output)-1)
output = output & "]"
End If

Response.Write output
```

That's all...